# Vice versa colors for on and off hover of buttons

Tags: website-design, color-scheme, css, hover

How should we choose the color for buttons is there a should always be a dark and light colour or two differed colors. What will be the best strategy for choosing colours.

And is it should always be a vice versa colors for on and off of hover of buttons links etc.

like when you hover on login or profile button etc

Comment: Sorry, this question is way too broad for a possible answer. Can you describe the exact situation like what the buttons will do, in what context, for which users etc? Also adding screenshots or wireframes will help. For now I vote to close the question.

Comment: i am asking about the general way of giving colors for buttons  for ex for sign in or post etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to determinate the color palette that you'll use for that project.

To determinate color palette, you need to pay attention to a few things:

- What is the brand color
- What's your product about
- Demographics

After you form the color palette you should follow few rules in terms of action colors.

Your color palette should be divided into three main (could be more) sections.

1. Warning (Alert) Colors
2. "GO" colors
3. Neutral colors

**Warning colors** are usually picked from the red palette. 
e.g., CANCEL, DELETE, QUIT, etc.

**"GO" colors** needs to create user's feeling of moving forward. 
e.g., CONTINUE, APPLY, AGREE, etc.

**Neutral colors** are defining "an extra features". 
e.g., MORE, EDIT, POST A COMMENT, etc.

**Difference between these types of buttons should be obvious.**

**Should you use opposite colors?**

> Depends on your style.

Best,

R

Comment: some what agree with your answer thank you for your contribution